# Eevee Normal pass: remap negative values

Tags: compositing-nodes, eevee-render-engine

Here's a result of Normal pass in Eevee:

[image]

Faces with normals in `-1..0` range are rendered black. Is it possible to remap this range to `0..1` using Compositor? Here's the desired result made with a material:

[image]

I tried to render Normals pass in 32b `.exr` but it seems that there's no information about these normals in there.

Comment: Does it have to be in the compositor? In the shader, you could always use a Map Range node. or do it the oldschool way - (`Normal Value` + `1` / `2`).

Comment: @ChristopherBennett I can do that in a shader (my second gif) but I want to be able to quickly render this: with a shader I'll need to override all the materials (and vanilla Eevee doesn't allow that), turn off all the effects like bloom/AO, then turn them back on...

Comment: Ahh, I see. Never mind then. Unfortunately I don't know how to do that in the compositor. I'll up-vote the question in the hopes that some user who is more knowledgeable in this area might happen by.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The image below gives a node set up that you could use in the compositor. It splits up the normal into its rgba values, takes the absolute value of each component (using the Math node with the "Absolute" setting), and then recombines them.

[image: Compositor Nodes]

Comment: Hi Eliot, thank you for response! This works on a cube, but a sphere shows that mapping is made, I think, 0..-1..0..1, not -1..0..1: there's a border going through 0 https://i.imgur.com/akyRE3e.png

Comment: @SergeyKritskiy Thanks for pointing that out.  I fixed the answer and also realized that I didn't even need the second branch of nodes since I could just use the Absolute Value math node.

Comment: Ugh I tried to fix that myself and solution was so simple (well, also 'to learn nodes'..). Thank you!